RuntimeError. Large language model with DirectML on win11+amd gpu
I follow Enable PyTorch with DirectML on Windows and can use AMD GPU to run simple code:
import torch
import torch_directml

dml = torch_directml.device()

#Test a simple operation
x = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype=torch.float32, device=dml)
y = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype=torch.float32, device=dml)
print(x + y)

tensor([2., 4., 6.], device='privateuseone:0')
But I gets stuck when using Breeze-7B LLM. Did I go wrong somewhere?

from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
import torch
import torch_directml

dml = torch_directml.device()

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
     "MediaTek-Research/Breeze-7B-Instruct-v1_0",
     torch_dtype=torch.float32,
)
model.to(dml)

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('MediaTek-Research/Breeze-7B-Instruct-v1_0')
tokenizer.padding_side = "right"
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

def get_completion_breeze(prompt):
     chat = [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
     input_text = tokenizer.apply_chat_template(chat, tokenize=False)
     input_tensors = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt").to(dml) # Move tensors to DirectML device
     input_tensors['attention_mask'] = torch.ones(input_tensors['input_ids'].shape, dtype=torch.long, device=dml) # Ensure attention_mask is also on the DirectML device
    
     outputs = model.generate(
         input_tensors["input_ids"],
         attention_mask=input_tensors['attention_mask'],
         max_new_tokens=200,
         top_p=0.01,
         top_k=85,
         repetition_penalty=1.1,
         temperature=0.01
     )
    
     result = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
     return result

print(get_completion_breeze("hi"))

PS C:\Users\hung> & C:/Users/hung/miniconda3/envs/pydml/python.exe c:/Users/hung/Desktop/Breeze-7B.py
Loading checkpoint shards: 100%|███████████████████████| 4/4 [00:22<00:00, 5.72s/it]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\hung\Desktop\Breeze-7B.py", line 11, in
model.to(dml)
File "C:\Users\hung\miniconda3\envs\pydml\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py", line 2576, in to
return super().to(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\hung\miniconda3\envs\pydml\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1145, in to
return self._apply(convert)
File "C:\Users\hung\miniconda3\envs\pydml\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 797, in _apply
module._apply(fn)
File "C:\Users\hung\miniconda3\envs\pydml\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 797, in _apply
module._apply(fn)
File "C:\Users\hung\miniconda3\envs\pydml\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 797, in _apply
module._apply(fn)
[Previous line repeated 2 more times]
File "C:\Users\hung\miniconda3\envs\pydml\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 820, in _apply
param_applied = fn(param)
File "C:\Users\hung\miniconda3\envs\pydml\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1143, in convert
return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None, non_blocking)
RuntimeError: Could not allocate tensor with 234881024 bytes. There is not enough GPU video memory available!
enter image description here
Is there any other way to use AMD GPU to speed up LLM operations? Two hours is really too long to run a long conversation on cpu.

And I can run the same model on my rtx2060+16gb ram PC use code:
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(     "MediaTek-Research/Breeze-7B-Instruct-v1_0",     device_map="auto",     torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,     offload_buffers=True ...     input_tensors["input_ids"].to("cuda") ... )
I tried changing FP32 to FP16 to run the above code(torch_directml) but still not enough memory.
